# zeromq performance test. What's the accurate latency?

Tags: zeromq

I'm using zmq to carry message across process, and I want to do some performance test to get the latency and throughout.

The official site gives the guide to tell [How to Run Performance Tests](http://zeromq.org/results:perf-howto)

For example, I tried:

```
local_lat tcp://*:15213 200 100000
remote_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:15213 200 100000
```

and get the result:

```
message size: 200 [B]
roundtrip count: 100000
average latency: 13.845 [us]
```

But when trying the [pub-sub example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out) in C++, I found the time interval between sending and receiving is about 150us. (I get the result by print log with timestamp)

Could anybody explain the difference between these two?

**EDIT:**
I found the question [0mq: pubsub latency continually growing with messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412694/0mq-pubsub-latency-continually-growing-with-messages) The result give a nearly constant delay of 0.00015s, which is 150us, same as my test, 10x than the official performance test. Why is the difference?

Comment: A great & important feature of the StackOverflow Community principles is, that members are forced to present an **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example ) code / data** that demonstrates the subject matter. You might want to update your post so as to meet this and to show some respect to the contributing members, who are professionals with passion to solve MCVE-related issues. **Anyway, cssmlulu, enjoy being an active member of this great community, StackOverflow undoubtedly is.**

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem: [ZeroMQ - pub / sub latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084242/zeromq-pub-sub-latency)

I ran wireshark on my example code which publishes a zeromq message every second. Here is the output of wireshark:

```
145  10.900249     10.0.1.6 -> 10.0.1.6     TCP 89 5557→51723 [PSH, ACK] Seq=158 Ack=95 Win=408192 Len=33 TSval=502262367 TSecr=502261368
146  10.900294     10.0.1.6 -> 10.0.1.6     TCP 56 51723→5557 [ACK] Seq=95 Ack=191 Win=408096 Len=0 TSval=502262367 TSecr=502262367
147  11.901993     10.0.1.6 -> 10.0.1.6     TCP 89 5557→51723 [PSH, ACK] Seq=191 Ack=95 Win=408192 Len=33 TSval=502263367 TSecr=502262367
148  11.902041     10.0.1.6 -> 10.0.1.6     TCP 56 51723→5557 [ACK] Seq=95 Ack=224 Win=408064 Len=0 TSval=502263367 TSecr=502263367
```

As you can see it's taking about 45 microseconds to send and acknowledge each message. At first I thought that the connection was getting re-established on each message but that's not it. So I turned my attention to the receiver...

```
while(true)
    if(subscriver.recv(&message, ZMQ_NOBLOCK)) {
        // print time
    }
}
```

By adding the ZMQ_NOBLOCK and polling in a hard while loop I got the time down to 100us. That still seems large and it comes at the price of spiking one core. But I do feel like I understand the problem slightly better. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: 100us seams similar to my experimet. But what do you mean by "the price of spiking one core"?

Comment: The line:
    while(true) {

will run one of the CPU cores at 100%.

Comment: Also, I profiled deeply into the zeromq code and had some insights. Are you using a mac?